# How to create a user defined task in synology?

Tags: task, scheduler, synology

I want to create a task that should run a file containing script every day in synology

Answer (score 0):

There is scheduler in control panel. Put your script in any folder you want and run it from scheduler.

Choose `user defined script`

mine looks like

`/volume1/MainData/Programs/Scripts/Bash/Synology/rsync_work_backup.sh`

Comment: i put this in to user defined column. is it work? 
/volume1/web/ScheduleCalendarNew/custschedule.php

Comment: no, not in that form. php script should be run by `/usr/bin/php <phpscript>`  Also in synology there is possibility to install php5 and php7 at the same time. Then php may looks like `/usr/bin/php50` or 7, just look at php folder.